# What happens when two processes are trying to access a critical section with semaphore = 0?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, semaphore

In my code I do the following initialization :

```
struct PipeShm myPipe = { .init = 0 , .flag = FALSE , .mutex = NULL , .ptr1 = NULL , .ptr2 = NULL ,
        .status1 = -10 , .status2 = -10 , .semaphoreFlag = FALSE };

int initPipe()
{
    if (!myPipe.init)
    {
        myPipe.mutex = mmap (NULL, sizeof *myPipe.mutex, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

        if (!sem_init (myPipe.mutex, 1, 0))  // semaphore is initialized to 0
        {
            myPipe.init = TRUE;
        }
        else
            perror ("initPipe");
    }
    return 1;   // always successful
}
```

I can have multiple processes that can be invoked from `main()` (note the **fork**) .

Thanks

Comment: You are calling `fork()` twice: once at the start and once inside the if conditional

Comment: @knittl: Okay , and what's wrong with that ? this is done intentionally

Comment: You have 4 processes in the end (parent and child both fork() again). The processes from the second fork (`if(fork())`) will each have a distinct copy of the original semaphore.

Comment: @knittl: The `fork` in the `if` is taking care of the output , 1 output each time . If I add a fork before that , then I should be expecting `2` output ...or not ?  .... And yes I know that they would have 2 copies , but even though , there are times that I get `1` output only .! why ?

Comment: Likely to be a race condition. Order of execution after fork is not specified. Context switch might occur anywhere after calling fork, you never know if child or parent will be executed first.

Comment: @knittl: Race indeed :) then I have no way to control that ?

Comment: The race condition can be controlled; it just requires care.  You've not shown the `myPipe` structure, or the `my_pipe()` function, so there's a lot of guesswork required to make the code compile, much less simulate.  Look up SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example), but note that [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/) appears to be having problems or appears to be offline.  (Google has a cache at the moment.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Done and added at the end of the post . Please see edited post . thanks

Comment: Are you trying to simulate a pipe with shared memory and semaphores?  Why not use a real pipe?  It would be a lot easier.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: This is homework :) this is what the TA & lecturer want... on my free time I'm always using `pipe()`

Comment: If you're using `shmget()`, you also need to use `shmat()` to attach the shared memory to your process.  Your code does not show that.  There are two separate sets of shared memory functions in POSIX; the 'System V IPC' set (`shmget()`, `shmat()`, `shmdt()`, `shmctl()` from `<sys/shm.h>`) and the POSIX set (`shm_open()`, `shm_unlink()` from `<sys/mman.h>`).  You need to revisit how your pipes are meant to work from the ground up, I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The un-named pipe is done with Sys V , and the named pipe is using Posix . That's why you see two different implementations ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: BTW , I think that this is somehow related to the semaphores , since the only way a process can read or write is when he has permission to enter the critical section , but from some reason the semaphore is not enough to restrict a process , when there is another process that's currently reading / writing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICS your error is in your control variables. Only your `mutex` variable is shared between the processes, not your `init` or `flag` variables. These are copy on write, so you wouldn't see the changes in a different process.

You'd have to pack all of your control variables inside the segment that you create. Create an appropriate `struct` type for all the fields that you need.

BTW, calling a semaphore `mutex` is really a bad idea. A mutex has a semantic that is quite different from a semaphore. (Or if you really use it as a mutex, I didn't check, use `pthread_mutex_t` with `pshared` in the initializer.)

**Edit after your edit:** No it wouldn't work like this. You really have to place the whole `struct` in the shared segment. So your `struct PipeShm` must contain a `sem_t sem` and not a `sem_t* mutex`. Then you'd do something like

```
struct PipeShm * myPipe = 0;

int initPipe()
{
    if (!myPipe->init)
    {
        myPipe = mmap (NULL, sizeof *myPipe, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

        if (!sem_init (myPipe->sem, 1, 0))  // semaphore is initialized to 0
        {
            myPipe->init = true;
        }
        else
            perror ("initPipe");
    }
    return 1;   // always successful
}
```

Other things you should be aware of:

- The `sem_t` interfaces can be interrupted by any kind of IO or other signals. You always have to check
  the return of these functions and in particular restart the function
  if it received `EINTR`.
- Mondern C has a Boolean. This you can easily use by including
  `<stdbool.h>` through names of `bool`, `false` and `true`.

Comment: I did that already , and it still continues.Please see the edited post with modifications of the struct . I have the struct in the `H` file , and I initialize it in the `C` file

Comment: But I use `sem_wait()` in my code , and its prototype is `int sem_wait(sem_t *sem);` , e.g. it gets a pointer as a parameter ...

Comment: I put a `&` and it compiles. However the problem still stands , even after I made the exact modifications you wrote. Something is very weird with this , man :)