# Is it possible to create a global semaphore for all processes?

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

I have a problem with a semaphore in my code.

This is a struct that I built:

```
struct PipeShm
{
        // doesn't matter 
        sem_t *mutex;
        int init;
        // more fields
};
```

Here I initialize the struct:

```
struct PipeShm myPipe ;
myPipe.mutex = NULL;
myPipe.init = 0;
```

And I use an initialization method:

```
int initMethod()
{
    if (!myPipe.init)
    {
        myPipe.mutex = mmap (NULL, sizeof *myPipe.mutex, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        if (!sem_init (myPipe.mutex, 1, 0))
        {
            myPipe.init = TRUE;
        }
        else
            perror ("initMethod");
    }
    return 1;   
}
```

This is a simple main that uses the above :

```
int main()

{
    int spd, pid, rb;
    char buff[4096];


    shm_pipe_init();
    fork();

        // more code goes here 

        return 0;
}
```

In the line `fork();` (please correct me if I'm wrong) the `2` processes would 
have the two different semaphores, right?

If so, I want to make the a global semaphore. Is that possible?

Due to problems of synchronization in my code, I suspect that the main reason is 
a double semaphore for each created process.

Comment: @tbert: I can't use that (files , I mean)

Comment: then you might want to look at your man pages, because "man sem_init" led me to "sem_open", which says "The sem_open() function establishes a connection between a named semaphore and a process" which looks exactly like what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Your code to create and initialize the semaphore looks like you are trying to do the right thing. Did you run into a specific problem when using the semaphore?

Comment: @user315052: Yes , my processes keep run into to each other , even though that I use semaphores and locking . I really have no idea what causes this , I tried to debug this countless times , but nada . My only conclusion is that the semaphore is not shared between all processes , and that makes all hell brake loose ...For example : instead of getting `2 outputs` when I `fork` , I get once `2 outputs` and another time  `1 output`

Comment: I already told you for your other question on the same subject, that you have to have the `init` field also inside the shared segment, this can't work like that. You have to have your whole shared control structure in the segment. Did you see my answer, there? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708049/what-happens-when-two-processes-are-trying-to-access-a-critical-section-with-sem

Comment: @JensGustedt: That shouldn't be necessary if the semaphore is initialized before the `fork`. But if the init routine is being called after the `fork` call, you are right that the init flag is required to be in the shared memory too.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Jens , I did exactly what you said and I still get the same result . Shall I upload the new code so you can take a look and maybe tell me if you see something wrong ? much appreciated !

Comment: @ron, first create a minimal example that exactly reproduces your problem. This should only be some lines long, complete, and reliably reproduce the problem (on your platform). Usually by creating such and example, you find the error :) Once you have such an example and your professor isn't able or willing to help you out, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code to initialize the semaphore appears to be correct, so you will have to look elsewhere for your synchronization problems. Below is a test program that illustrates working behavior for your code:

```
void do_child () {
    fprintf(stderr, "[%u] child: waiting...\n", (unsigned)time(0));
    sem_wait(myPipe.mutex);
    fprintf(stderr, "[%u] child: sleeping 1...\n", (unsigned)time(0));
    sleep(1);
    fprintf(stderr, "[%u] child: posting...\n", (unsigned)time(0));
    sem_post(myPipe.mutex);
    fprintf(stderr, "[%u] child: done...\n", (unsigned)time(0));
}

void do_parent (pid_t p) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[%u] parent: sleeping 5...\n", (unsigned)time(0));
    sleep(5);
    fprintf(stderr, "[%u] parent: posting...\n", (unsigned)time(0));
    sem_post(myPipe.mutex);
    fprintf(stderr, "[%u] parent: waiting...\n", (unsigned)time(0));
    sem_wait(myPipe.mutex);
    fprintf(stderr, "[%u] parent: waitpid...\n", (unsigned)time(0));
    waitpid(p, 0, 0);
    fprintf(stderr, "[%u] parent: done...\n", (unsigned)time(0));
}

int main () {
    pid_t p;
    myPipe.mutex = NULL;
    myPipe.init = 0;
    initMethod();
    switch ((p = fork())) {
    case 0:  do_child(); break;
    case -1: perror("fork"); break;
    default: do_parent(p); break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think you would already know, but just in case, a semaphore is not really a mutex. You can think of a mutex as a semaphore that is initialized to a post value of `1`. But, a semaphore does not prevent multiple simultaneous posts. If you have spurious posts to the semaphore, this will allow more than one thread to go into the critical section.